# Can a communication server port be used to send data unrelated to a filter-driver?

Tags: c, driver, ndis, minifilter, wfp

I have a question regarding the use of [communication ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltcreatecommunicationport) in driver development on a Windows 10 platform (x64).

Let's assume that I have a driver which acts as both a filesystem filter/mini-filter driver which logs file-system activity but which also subscribes a routine to callback notifications using [PSSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutine) for example.

Would it then be possible to send data collected using the callback routine through the communication port to a user-mode application ? Or are these communication ports dedicated to file-system filter/mini-filter drivers ? Is this a good practice ?

I am trying to find a generic way of sending/streaming data from the Kernel-mode driver to a user-mode service whether it be data collected collected using WFP (NDIS) concerning network traffic, File-system activity (filter/mini-filter) or a supplied callback routine (PSSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine for example).

I want to avoid having multiple communication channels with the user-mode service...

I only want to use a dedicated communication channel to stream data to the user-mode service, the driver will use IOCTL codes received from user-mode requests but for very specific things to configure the driver.

The main thing is that I want a single channel to stream all the data to the service...

Comment: I mean, you could use it. You need a `FLT_FILTER` object which is created via [`FltRegisterFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltregisterfilter), but you don't need to actually implement any filtering. I think this functionality is intended specifically for filter drivers, though I don't know if there are any issues with using it otherwise. The only problem is that it can't be used at DISPATCH_LEVEL, which a lot of these callbacks operate at (though you could spin it off onto a worker thread).

Comment: @Luke, can you elaborate on why I would need to spawn a new thread ?

Comment: I'm thinking primarily of WFP callouts which are generally invoked at DISPATCH_LEVEL. FltSendMessage() only supports APC_LEVEL.